# get the href attribute of an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a userscript for YouTube and I need to retrieve the href attribute of an `<a>` tag through the class name.

This was my attempt but it just returned "undefined":

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mix-playlist").getAttribute("href");
console.log(x);
```

```html
<a class="XY XY XY mix-playlist XY" href="XY"></a>
```

Thanks for your help!

Nevermind, I figured it out. I just had to move it into this function:
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {`

and split the resulting array.

Sorry for the duplicate but I just couldn't gather much information after looking through stackoverflow questions for 20 minutes.

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mix-playlist")[0].getAttribute("href");`

Comment: @Mamun that returns "Execution of script failed! document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined"

Comment: May be you need put the code after HTML..

Comment: @Sv443 that likely means that the element is not yet in the DOM when you're trying to access it.

Comment: @Mamun I don't have much power over that with my tampermonkey addon but the script runs multiple times even when the element has fully loaded.

Comment: JavaScript:

    var elems = document.getElementsByTagname("A");

    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
          if (elems(i).className.indexOf('mix-playlist') != -1) {
                   alert(elems(i).getAttribute('href'));
          }
    }

Comment: Try to search for "how to run code after DOM loaded in JavaScript?"

Comment: If the JavaScript is in your `<head>`, which it should be for external caching reasons, then you need to put your JavaScript *(on the external JS page)* in a load Event, like `addEventListener('load', function(){ /* Elements are defined since page is loaded *});` or `var old = onload; /* change old var name if using technique on other pages */ onload = function(){ if(old)old(); /* execute if there is already a load Event - Elements are available now */ }`